Create pdf output file alternating pages between two files
I have a pdf file, let's call it A, composed of a lot of pages.
Then I have a second pdf file, let's call it B, composed of a single page.
My goal is to have an output file, let's call it O, with the following pattern:
O[1] = A[1]
O[2] = B[1]
O[3] = A[2]
O[4] = B[1]
O[5] = A[3]
O[6] = B[1]
O[7] = A[4]
O[8] = B[1]
...

In other words, I want to interleaving the pages of A with page B.
To give you a background, file A contains the slides of a course I've attended, I created file B with a single page filled by horizontal lines.
The resulting output file will allow me to place my notes on the right side of the slides (since I'm going to print two pages per sheet).
I'm able to do this importing every single page in LibreOffice, but I'm looking for a script (perhaps pdftk?) to easily run against different files.

Do any of these answers help? Topmost one is using pdftk: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53295/how-to-merge-2-pdf-files-with-interleaving-pages-order

Does this answer your question? How to merge 2 PDF files with interleaving pages order?

It's about collating pages, here with B as odd/recto and A as even/verso (given OP's exact requirement), except there are not enough B pages available: they'll have to be duplicated enough times in a first operation.
If A pages (thus verso) are to be seen at the left of B pages, then there should be one guard recto page first: for example an additional B page.

count the number of pages in A. Say there are 10 pages.
That means one additional B front page will be needed for a total of 10+1 = 11 (or as seen below 0 to 10). If there's a way to automate this count, it should be used as the upper value for the loop below. I don't know such way.

generate enough B pages (B's unique page B1) in a shell loop to duplicate from a first pdftk command, and feed them through stdout to a second pdftk command which will use stdin for the B part and will collate them along A.
pdftk B=B.pdf cat $(for page in $(seq 0 10); do echo B1; done) output - | pdftk A=A.pdf B=- shuffle B A output O.pdf

or the same split in a more readable form:
pdftk B=B.pdf \
      cat $(for page in $(seq 0 10); do echo B1; done) \
      output - | \
pdftk A=A.pdf \
      B=- \
      shuffle B A \
      output O.pdf

Note: if that was not clear, once the shell loop is unrolled, this resolves into:
pdftk B=B.pdf cat B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 B1 output - | pdftk A=A.pdf B=- shuffle B A output O.pdf



Should the page order be inverted between A and B (to start printing with an A page, rather than a B page), probably generate one less page in B (the last B page would probably not be needed) and change shuffle B A into shuffle A B in the last command.
Here the java (re-)implementation of pdftk, the one packaged in recent distributions, was used.

You can use qpdf
qpdf A.pdf --pages $(seq -f'. %.0f B.pdf 1' $(qpdf A.pdf --show-npages)) -- O.pdf

For more details see the excellent QPDF documentation.
